# Confirm or improve following multiplication of $2 \times 2$ matrix :

Tags: matrices

Our textbook says the following: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{22} \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Being a novice when it comes to matrices, I am not entirely sure but, shouldn't it be \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: You’re absolutely right.

Comment: It is OK...........

Comment: Yes, it should.